# Is $A' ∩ C'$ the same thing as $(A ∩ C)'$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is $A' \cap C'$ the same thing as $(A \cap C)'$ ? Here ' means the complementary set.

Comment: What do you mean by $A'$?

Comment: DRAW A PICTURE, Draw a box with two overlapping circles in it, start there!

Comment: Complement of $A$ @TimRaczkowski

Comment: Can you come up with a counter-example?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Omega = \{1, 2, 3\}, A = \{2, 3\}, C = \{3\}$. Now calculate $A' \cap C'$ and $(A \cap C)'$. What does that tell you?

Answer (score 0):

Almost, but you have to switch the union/intersection when you negate it.  (I don't know how to make the symbols!)

Comment: Latex is your, well, not friend. But it can be helpful. See http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help for some examples. Union is \cup and intersection is \cap.

Answer (score 0):

$A'\cap C'$ is the same as $(A\cup C)'$

Answer (score 0):

No, using [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) you can show that (A ∩ C)' = (A' ∪ C')

Answer (score 0):

These two sets are not equal, an element from $A$ which doesn't belong to $B$ is in $(A\cap B)'$ but not in $A'\cap B'$.